# Creating email signature for outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I made an email signature in HTML. I have written my HTML email signature and see it in Google Chrome. The problem is, as soon as I copied it to Outlook, my HTML Email signature shows some white gap between its row. I tried everything but I can't get rid of it. White space is only showing in Ms Outlook, but not in Google Chrome, Gmail, etc. Can anyone help me? Code below. [See screenshot of the email signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXnL1.png)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:15px; line-height:20px">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:28px; font-size: 25px;color:#000; ">   
                    <strong style="color: #C40F10">Amy Strom</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:20px; font-size: 16px;color:#393934; ">
                    Property Manager
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:20px; font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap;color: #393934;">
                    P:&nbsp;<a href="tel:+61894942606" style="text-decoration:underline;color: #393934;text-decoration: none;">(08)&nbsp;9494&nbsp;2606</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:20px; font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap;">
                    E:&nbsp;<a href="mailto:pm3@semplepg.com.au" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934">pm3@semplepg.com.au</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:20px; font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap;">
                    <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/TE3mL2dZiA2pmk7P7" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934">1/752 North Lake Road, South Lake WA 6164</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td  valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; line-height:20px; font-size: 16px;white-space:nowrap;">
                    <a href="https://www.semplepg.com.au/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #C40F10">www.semplepg.com.au</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td  valign="top"  style="padding: 2px 0 0 20px; text-align:center;" valign="bottom">
        <a href="https://www.semplepg.com.au/">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/6177c1e3331ea605e1a4d562_AmyStrom.jpg" alt="Amy's photo from Semple Property" width="250" style="width:250;font-family: sans-serif; color: #ffffff; display: block; border: 0px;">
        </a> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td  valign="top"  style="background-color:#3C3C3B; padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px; font-size:0px; line-height:0; text-align:left; ">
        <a href="mailto:semple@semplepg.com.au" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61d5150d56c5f0bb75b_mail.png" alt= "email icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
        <a href="https://au.linkedin.com/company/semplepropertygroup" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61ead014f5bfb8600fe_linkedin.png" alt= "Linkedin icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgSovBlmEFHzyXx-bW9vEbw" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61d4f490af276680554_youtube.png" alt= "Youtube icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/semplepropertygroup" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61d541a51c3b0433623_fb.png" alt= "Facebook icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/semple_property_group/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61e0a63f40c878b6465_instagram.png" alt= "Instagram icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
        <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/jWt8je8pFnN8Vi2m8" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/616fd61d32add34ce0116798_location.png" alt= "Location icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td   valign="top"  style="background-color:#3C3C3B; padding: 5px 20px 5px 12px; text-align:right; ">

        <a href="https://www.ratemyagent.com.au/real-estate-agency/semple-property-group-ao219/sales/reviews" style="text-decoration: none; color: #393934; padding-right:5px; display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5e708a896f96221b4a9d76bc/61554ae7255348ced3b9293a_rate.png" alt= "Location icon" height="35" style="height: 35px;">
        </a>
        
    </td>

</tr></table>
```

Comment: On this line you have valign top as well as valign bottom. Try removing valign bottom: `<td  valign="top"  style="padding: 2px 0 0 20px; text-align:center;" valign="bottom">`